# SQL Server : How to use variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying the following query and it works as I expect it to

`SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CAST(MAX(party_id)+1 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) FROM PARTY`

The result is:

> 0147

But when I execute the following query so that I can store this value in a variable

```
DECLARE @pid varchar;
SELECT @pid = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(MAX(party_id)+1 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) FROM PARTY
SELECT @pid as party_id
```

it doesn't return `0147` as in the above query, instead what it returns is

> 0

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **always** define a **length** when you declare a `varchar` !!

This

```
DECLARE @pid varchar;
```

gives you a `varchar` of **exactly ONE character** length!!

Use

```
DECLARE @pid varchar(20);
```

and your problem is solved ...

Comment: marc_s there is a default length IIR...no ? ( or is it for the nvar...))

Comment: @RoyiNamir: yes: **ONE** character. When using a `varchar` without length in the context of a `CAST` or `CONVERT`, it's 30 characters - but when you define a variable, it's 1 character

Comment: Marc , yes I got confused with this info : _"When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30."_

Comment: same time :-)...(tnx)

Answer (score 2):

Yo have not declared size of varchar that is why it is truncating.
Set size sufficiently large to store result.

```
DECLARE @pid varchar(10);
SELECT @pid = RIGHT('0000' + CAST(MAX(party_id)+1 AS VARCHAR(4)),4) FROM PARTY
SELECT @pid as party_id
```

[From SQL Server MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

> **varchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n
> defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max
> indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The
> storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The
> ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.
>
> **When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration**
> **statement, the default length is 1.**

Answer (score 0):

`DECLARE @pid varchar;` implies a varchar of length 1.

Try `DECLARE @pid varchar(4);`